# d3.js hierarchical edge bundling: embed json data in variable

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I would like to read the json data directly in a variable, for instance

```
var HEBdata = [
{"name":"test.cluster1.item1","imports":["test.cluster1.item2","test.cluster1.item3"]},
{"name":"test.cluster1.item2","imports":["test.cluster1.item3"]},
{"name":"test.cluster1.item3"}
];
```

I would then use this variable here

```
d3.json(HEBdata, function(error, classes) {
  if (error) throw error;
```

Instead of

```
d3.json("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/mbostock/1044242/raw/8f22cf2264e1f6ec6cb233c4b49333fb8f75bb99/readme-flare-imports.json", function(error, classes) {
  if (error) throw error;
```

Here is a fiddle with the code that you may change: https://fiddle.jshell.net/d1766z4r/ (the URL has been commented and replaced by the HEBdata variable)

I would like to do this to be able to use custom data to make it simple for another question that I want to ask later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use d3.json. instead just assign the object to your var `classes`.

d3.json essentially does this:

> loads data into the browser using an XMLHttpRequest, or XHR. This allows data to be loaded asynchronously (so the rest of the page can display while data is loading), and is safer than JSONP. D3’s xhr module simplifies loading and parsing data. When loading data asynchronously, code that depends on the loaded data should generally exist within the callback function. Code that doesn't depend on data can run immediately when the page loads.

https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Requests.md

Since you already have your data ready, you don't have to wait to use it. So any code that would normally have to wait to run until the Http response is received can be run straight away like so:

```js
var classes = [
{"name":"test.cluster1.item1","imports":["test.cluster1.item2","test.cluster1.item3"]},
{"name":"test.cluster1.item2","imports":["test.cluster1.item3"]},
{"name":"test.cluster1.item3"}
];

var diameter = 960,
    radius = diameter / 2,
    innerRadius = radius - 120;

var cluster = d3.layout.cluster()
    .size([360, innerRadius])
    .sort(null)
    .value(function(d) { return d.size; });

var bundle = d3.layout.bundle();

var line = d3.svg.line.radial()
    .interpolate("bundle")
    .tension(.85)
    .radius(function(d) { return d.y; })
    .angle(function(d) { return d.x / 180 * Math.PI; });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", diameter)
    .attr("height", diameter)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + radius + "," + radius + ")");

var link = svg.append("g").selectAll(".link"),
    node = svg.append("g").selectAll(".node");

//d3.json("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/mbostock/1044242/raw/8f22cf2264e1f6ec6cb233c4b49333fb8f75bb99/readme-flare-imports.json", function(error, classes) {
  //if (error) throw error;

  var nodes = cluster.nodes(packageHierarchy(classes)),
      links = packageImports(nodes);

  link = link
      .data(bundle(links))
    .enter().append("path")
      .each(function(d) { d.source = d[0], d.target = d[d.length - 1]; })
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr("d", line);

  node = node
      .data(nodes.filter(function(n) { return !n.children; }))
    .enter().append("text")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("dy", ".31em")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "rotate(" + (d.x - 90) + ")translate(" + (d.y + 8) + ",0)" + (d.x < 180 ? "" : "rotate(180)"); })
      .style("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.x < 180 ? "start" : "end"; })
      .text(function(d) { return d.key; })
      .on("mouseover", mouseovered)
      .on("mouseout", mouseouted);
//});

function mouseovered(d) {
  node
      .each(function(n) { n.target = n.source = false; });

  link
      .classed("link--target", function(l) { if (l.target === d) return l.source.source = true; })
      .classed("link--source", function(l) { if (l.source === d) return l.target.target = true; })
    .filter(function(l) { return l.target === d || l.source === d; })
      .each(function() { this.parentNode.appendChild(this); });

  node
      .classed("node--target", function(n) { return n.target; })
      .classed("node--source", function(n) { return n.source; });
}

function mouseouted(d) {
  link
      .classed("link--target", false)
      .classed("link--source", false);

  node
      .classed("node--target", false)
      .classed("node--source", false);
}

d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", diameter + "px");

// Lazily construct the package hierarchy from class names.
function packageHierarchy(classes) {
  var map = {};

  function find(name, data) {
    var node = map[name], i;
    if (!node) {
      node = map[name] = data || {name: name, children: []};
      if (name.length) {
        node.parent = find(name.substring(0, i = name.lastIndexOf(".")));
        node.parent.children.push(node);
        node.key = name.substring(i + 1);
      }
    }
    return node;
  }

  classes.forEach(function(d) {
    find(d.name, d);
  });

  return map[""];
}

// Return a list of imports for the given array of nodes.
function packageImports(nodes) {
  var map = {},
      imports = [];

  // Compute a map from name to node.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    map[d.name] = d;
  });

  // For each import, construct a link from the source to target node.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    if (d.imports) d.imports.forEach(function(i) {
      imports.push({source: map[d.name], target: map[i]});
    });
  });

  return imports;
}
```

```css
.node {
  font: 300 11px "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  fill: #bbb;
}

.node:hover {
  fill: #000;
}

.link {
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-opacity: .4;
  fill: none;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Fiddle:https://fiddle.jshell.net/ga1s8bn7/